# How to get map view of file just have only ifstream?

Tags: c++, linux, file, winapi, cross-platform

I need to create file mapping and get map view of file for my ifstream.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 
    NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);  
    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    HANDLE hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
    if (hFileMap != NULL) 
    {
        BYTE *pData = (BYTE *)MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, dwFileSize); 
        if (pData != NULL)  
        {
            fillDllInfo(pData, dwFileSize);
            UnmapViewOfFile(pData);         
        }
```

Here I creating file, and so on. But i need to do something like this

```
std::ifstream pefile;
pefile.open(this->fileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(!pefile.is_open())   
    return error(erId::Cant_Open_File);
    std::streamoff filesize = pefile.tellg();
    //HANDLE hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
    //if (hFileMap != NULL) 
    //{
    //  BYTE *pData = (BYTE *)MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, dwFileSize); 
    //  if (pData != NULL)  
        //{
            fillDllInfo(pData /* ??? */, filesize );
        //  UnmapViewOfFile(pData);         
        //}
```

and work with my pefile! How can i get pData on my pefile whithout boost or anything else?
Thanks!

Comment: There are no portable way to map a file in memory. You have to use the windows API. What's wrong with your first code?

Comment: I need to create cross platform app. Nothing, it's working. :)
So I need to use boost anyway? :(

Comment: You know PE files only work on windows, right?

Comment: Yes.:) But PE files can exist in other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping the file in memory, you can load all of it in a buffer. It's a lot less efficient but it's portable.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> // memcpy

void fillDllInfo (char* buf, size_t size)
{
  // ...
}

char* read_whole_stream (std::ifstream& stream, size_t& size)
{
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
  std::string s (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), eos);
  char* buf = new char[s.size()];
  memcpy(buf, s.c_str(), s.size());
  return buf;
}

int main ()
{
  std::ifstream pefile;
  pefile.open("in", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

  if (!pefile.is_open())
    return 1;

  size_t filesize;
  char* pData = read_whole_stream(pefile, filesize);
  fillDllInfo(pData, filesize);
  delete[] pData;

  return 0;
}
```